# wireshark skype messages

Tags: wireshark, skype

I would like to analyse packets sent by skype from my computer.
Particularly I am interested in packets that transmit messages.

With what filter I can see this packets on wireshark.
I know that dropbox is using it's own protocol for synchronizing file lists between clients, so I am wondering is there a specific protocol that skype is using.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of packets don't transmit messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, Wireshark doesn't have explicit Skype support yet so you won't get pretty decodes. If you're wiling to compile from source, you can [build it in](https://github.com/matthiasbock/OpenSkype/wiki/Wireshark).

Second, [Skype encrypts everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype_protocol) so there isn't much to look at once you get the packets.

Third, it doesn't use a predictable port unless egress to the network is restricted to only allow TCP/80 or TCP/443, so you'll have to find them in the swarm of normal traffic. But that should be easy if you've properly isolated your network connections.

Comment: Although I would note that skype will also use UDP if it does not detect NAT/Firewalls in the way.

Comment: I am aware that skype encrypts all the outputs. I was just interested what protocol does it use to send messages and how I can look at them in wireshark

Comment: You cannot look into the encrytped traffic that easy. Otherwise encription would be pointless and Wireshark will only give you encrypted traffic that will look pretty much like garbage.